# Date formatting options in HANA

Tags: hana

I am trying to convert date column to this format: `May 28, 2018 2:44:47.883 PM`. I am using this query to do that:

```
SELECT
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
TO_NVARCHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Mon DD, YYYY HH:MM:ss')
FROM Dummy
```

But, no luck yet. What date formatting options are available in HANA?

### Edit

Query output:

```
May 29, 2018 1:53:13.055 PM       May 29, 2018 01:05:13
```

As you can see, `MM` is being considered as **month** instead of minutes. And I have no idea how can I ask for 3-digit milliseconds, following by AM / PM.

Comment: Hi, can you share the output of that query?

Comment: @NelsonMiranda, done

Comment: Hi, can you try 'Mon DD, YYYY HH:MI:SS' ?

Comment: @NelsonMiranda, my minutes are in-place now: `May 29, 2018 02:54:28`, milliseconds and AM / PM to go... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try 'Mon DD, YYYY HH:MI:SS'.

From [SAP HANA documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/3f81ccc7e35d44cbbc595c7d552c202a.html):

> TIME
>
> The TIME data type consists of hour, minute, and second information to
>   represent a time value. The default format for the TIME data type is
>   HH24:MI:SS. HH24 represents the hour from 0 to 24, MI represents the
>   minute from 0 to 59, and SS represents the second from 0 to 59.